# Highcharts remove zero value labels

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm implementing highcharts in my site, however is proving challenging from a presentation point of view.

My data loads fine, but for the series, some of the values are zeros. I would like to display the label when not zero, as otherwise it becomes hard to read.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
   column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
           enabled: this.value == 0 ? false : true,
       color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white' }
}
}
```

But this is not working. I've tried using only 'this' instead of value but also doesn't pick it up. 
I haven't been able to find a default option from the library that would allow me to do this without having to create custom code.

I've checked a few approaches, but the zeros are in one of the series. So i still want to present the label for the values that aren't zeros for the group.

I think when one says this.y it takes the value of the entire group, and not the individual series...

Any suggestions? Clearly I'm doing something wrong!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you tried using the `formatter` option for `dataLabels`? You should be able to access your data within that and decide what the label should look like. Here you can check for zero and just return `null` shown below.

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: colors[0],
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    formatter: function() {
        if (this.y != 0) {
          return this.y +'%';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you are having trouble figuring out what part of your data to look at, use `console.log(this)` in the formatter function so you can see the object you are working with.

Check out this working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/VLmKK/69/

Hope that helps!

Update: Return null instead of empty string to avoid creation of an invisible label as mentioned in the comments by Brett. Thanks.

You may also [not return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709838/903011) on zero values.

Comment: @Lievcin: The formatter option handles each value individually just as you would like. I tested it in the highchart sample files. It only removed labels from data points that were 0. Were you able to try it out?

Comment: For labels you do not want to show you must return `null`, not an empty string, otherwise a seemingly invisible label is drawn. This becomes visible if you have border, background, and corner radius applied. [refer to this fiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4r2w/3/), notice the round shadow where the zero value is. [now see when returning null](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4r2w/4/).

Comment: @BrettRyan Thanks, I updated the answer to reflect your finding.

Comment: Having had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709838/903011), the solution for me was to not return anything but non-zero values

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success where instead of using a custom formatter I replace my zero values in the series data with nulls.  this seems to suppress the datalabel and data from  being represented on the chart but still keeps it present on the legend.